# How to add scale in slider control in html5 input tag

Tags: html

Is there any way we could include a scale in slider. I haven't found any attribute to do that.

Comment: Consider using a background image with equally spaced ticks & manipulating the `step` attribute of input type=range control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make tick marks on the slider , you will have to use the attribute called `list` and it should be linked to `<datalist>` tag of HTML5

```
<input type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 step=20 list=tickmarks>
<datalist id=tickmarks>
<option>0</option>
<option>20</option>
<option>40</option>
<option>60</option>
<option>80</option>
<option>100</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I have tried this. Is there any way we could add a scale. Like, a mark for every 10 units. Is there any attribute to do this.

Comment: @Subbu How can we show values together with ticks?. Just like measurement scale

Comment: how can add vertical scale with label of every step

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox by now, Chrome supports it though.

Comment: 93.66 % of all browser supports it (source. https://caniuse.com/?search=datalist)

Answer (score 3):

First of all I should appreciate @Subbu answer which is helpful but I suppose there are some details which are needed to be dealt with.

1. You can utilize `datalist` but it doesn't work in Firefox, Chrome supports it though, there is a workaround, see sample below which covers most of browsers:

```css
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, 
    #ccc, 
    #ccc 10%, 
    #000 10%, 
    #000 11%, 
    #ccc 11%, 
    #ccc 20%);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" list="steplist">
<datalist id="steplist">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>75</option>
    <option>100</option>
</datalist>
```

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26613443/4344976) for more details.

2. If you consider to colorize the ticks, you simply set style for input like below sample (Chrome only):

```html
<input type="range" style="color:red" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" list="tickmarks"/>
<datalist id="tickmarks"><option>0</option><option>5</option><option>10</option></datalist>
```

But you won't be able to style it based on what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Styling_HTML_forms) says:

> Some elements simply can't be styled using CSS. These include all advanced user interface widgets such as range, color, or date controls as well as all the dropdown widgets, including , ,  and  elements. The file picker widget is also known not to be stylable at all. The new  and  elements also fall in this category.

3. You might need a vertical range input, in that case the tricky way for Firefox needs to change, simply change the value for gradient, here is a simple example which specifies center point of the range input in Firefox while its orientation is vertical:

```css
input[orient=vertical][type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    #ccc, 
    #ccc 50%, 
    #000 50%, 
    #000 51%, 
    #ccc 51%, 
    #ccc 60%);
}
input[type=range][orient=vertical] {
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
    width: 30px;
    height: 150px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" orient="vertical" style="color:red; background:
#00f0;" min="0" max="10" value="3" step="1" list="tickmarks"/>
<datalist id="tickmarks"><option>5</option></datalist>
```